# How I tell my project to use the database in project folder

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I created database with ef code first.
I copied the 2 files that ef created to the project folder
`DAL.UsersDb.mdf` and `DAL.UsersDb_log.ldf`

Now I want to tell the project to use the new location.
I added them to `config` file  but its not working

```
<add name="UsersDb"
   connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;
   initial catalog=UsersDb;
             AttachDBFilename=|C:\Users\HOME\Desktop\MyProject|\DAL.Funcs+DataBase.mdf";
             integrated security=True;  MultipleActiveResultSets=True;  App=EntityFramework"
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I got the following Exception:

> Cannot open database \"DAL.UsersDb\" requested by the login. The login
>   failed.\r\nLogin failed for user 'HOME\598'.

```
public class UsersDb : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<BE.User> users { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Not clear. Put both codes. as before it was working. and now when it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Set the user on your application pool to "Local System". It has admin rights, it might be able to open the DB.

Answer (score 0):

may be the service user not have access to database, for testing you can pass user name and password in connection string

```
<add name="UsersDb"
       connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;
       initial catalog=UsersDb;
                 AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|C:\Users\X7\Desktop\MyProject\DAL.UsersDb.mdf;
                 user id=user;password=pass;  MultipleActiveResultSets=True;  App=EntityFramework"
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

And in deployment you can save the username and password in code and change connection string in code

[code supply the password to a connection string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170118/how-to-in-code-supply-the-password-to-a-connection-string-in-an-ado-net-entity-d)

Comment: still not work, Is there a guide or something that explains how to associate a data base
To another location, it should be apparent very simple

Comment: what is the connection string that used for debugging ?

Comment: @david i got this link can you try this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/12/09/using-localdb-with-full-iis-part-2-instance-ownership.aspx