# The RSA key container could not be opened app.config

Tags: .net, encryption, active-directory, rsa, app-config

I encrypt app.config using this manual [Encrypt connection string in app.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11637348/encrypt-connection-string-in-app-config).

I put the APP files to the shared folder and it works fine for my domain account but not for other users of the domain.

So I need to use encrypted app.config connection string sections for all users.

Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have used this method [How to in-code supply the password to a connection string in an ADO.Net Entity Data Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170118/how-to-in-code-supply-the-password-to-a-connection-string-in-an-ado-net-entity-d)

```
public MyDatabaseContainer() : base("name=MyDatabaseContainer")
{
    Database.Connection.ConnectionString = Database.Connection.ConnectionString.Replace("XXXXX","realpwd");
}
```