# Add credentials to connection string from code

Tags: c#, .net-core, openshift, connection-string

I have a connection string which uses username and password. However, the credentials are stored as environment variables (I'm using [OpenShift](https://www.openshift.com/)), so I would like to add the credentials (username and password) from the code, at runtime.

While I could probably achieve this using reg-ex, or some other creative ideas, it just seems like something that would be supported by default in C#. I found [this answer in another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170118/how-to-in-code-supply-the-password-to-a-connection-string-in-an-ado-net-entity-d/#answer-8170190), suggesting to use an [`EntityConnectionStringBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entityclient.entityconnectionstringbuilder?view=netframework-4.8), but this only works for .NET Framework (I'm using .NET Core 3.1). Is there anything similar for .NET Core (or maybe even smarter)?

Also I am using Entity Framework Core, so anything that modifies the connection itself, and not the connection string, is not really an option.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1&viewFallbackFrom=netcore-3.1?

Comment: @CodeCaster so all I had to do was change 'Enity' with 'Sql' :-). Thanks for the tip. If you want credit, please make a answer with a minimum example. If not, I'll make it myself, to help others.

Comment: Feel free to post your own!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @CodeCaster in the comments - the answer is the [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1&viewFallbackFrom=netcore-3.1). It allows adding sections, like `User ID` to an existing connection string. So to add username and password to a connections string from the `appsettings.json`, you can do something like this:

```
string baseConnStr = Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnectionString");

var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(baseConnStr);
builder.UserID = "Test";
builder.Password = "Abc123";

var connStr = builder.ConnectionString
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the config file something like this might work

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="Connection" connectionString="Url=https://smth.com; Username=Username; Password=Password" />
</connectionStrings>
```

and you just need to access the connection name

Comment: The problem is that the username and password only exists in OpenShift (the hosting environment), so it is unknown at compile time. Hence the request for a solution that works at runtime (which `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` does).